# Strategy: Exit a trade at 0.75 percent of entry price the next day or just before day closes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am new to pine script. I am trying to create a script to exit once 0.75 percent of entry price is reached (as target) the next day or exit just before end of day. But my script is only taking the close_all and ignoring the target part itself.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Please note that this script is going to be executed in **daily timeframe** only

```
//@version=5
strategy("test", overlay = true, process_orders_on_close = true)

var float entry_low = 0.0
per = (close-close[1]) / close[1] * 100


if per > 1
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
    entry_low := low

myOrderEntryPrice = strategy.position_avg_price

target = myOrderEntryPrice * 1.0075

strategy.exit("exit", profit = target, stop = entry_low)


strategy.close_all(when=dayofweek != dayofweek[1])
```

This is the code I tried to work with.